# how can I structure my plan learning korean?

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, korean

I am not a native speaker of Korean and not-native speaker English. I want to make a plan for learning Korean well and maybe arrive to B2 in July 2019.
I do not have a lot time because I get up 6 Am, I go to the school and I go out 1 PM next to work 1 PM to 9 PM.

I would like a plan good for learning Korean.

I was thinking in take 2 hour everyday and learning grammar in other day learning vocabulary and other day learning pronunciation, etc.

Comment: I tried to edit to make the question clearer. Please check I did not change the question in a bad way. The main question seems to be, how to structure a learning plan for Korean when the day is full of studies and working.

Comment: exactly @TommiBrander thank you for you help

Comment: You won't get to B2 in Korean in the next seven months with two hours per day. Maybe if you studied Korean as your full time job for the next seven months then you'd have a chance. For now you should just study with a good self teaching course for one hour and get a speaking partner for the other hour. Every day. That's your best chance with your limited time.

Comment: @AML if I take  4 hour everyday? 2 hour for learning grammatic and other 2 for learning vocabulary ?  because I think is important learn grammatic like vocabbulary from the k-pop,KDramas?

Comment: With your busy schedule, I would be impressed if you could even finish Pimsleur Korean 1-3. Also, what is your native language?

Comment: what is the best book for learning korean?